# Assign value to a combobox from a text variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I have the following problem. I have a table ( html ) in which the user selects a record and clicking a button will displays a modal containing 3 combobox and text input. When deployed modal I show in combos registry values ​​you select. The code I have is as follows:

```
$("#btn-editaregistro").click(function () {
$('#myModal').modal({
    show: 'false'
});

tipoSel = $('td', seleccionado).eq(0).text();
familiaSel = $('td', seleccionado).eq(1).text();
proveedorSel = $('td', seleccionado).eq(2).text();
vidaUtilSel = $('td', seleccionado).eq(3).text();
$("#list-tipo-modal option:text=" + tipoSel +"").attr("selected", "selected");
$("#list-familia-modal option:text=" + familiaSel +"").attr("selected", "selected");
$("#list-prov-modal option:text=" + proveedorSel +"").attr("selected", "selected"); 
$("#vida-util-modal").val(vidaUtilSel);

});
```

My modal HTML code:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Tipo </label>
        <select value="0" class="form-control" id="list-tipo-modal"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="bloque"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Familia</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="list-familia-modal"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="bloque"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Proveedor</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="list-prov-modal"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="bloque"><i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i> Vida útil</label>
        <input id="vida-util-modal" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        </div>
```

When printing the variables "Sel" if being saved , the problem is when I do the assignment to the corresponding combobox and sends me the following error " Uncaught Error: Syntax error , unrecognized expression: # list- type - modal option: text=Anilox " . Where " Anillox " is a value of a cell in my table.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is your jQuery selector!

Check this out

```js
$("#list-tipo-modal option[value=\"" + tipoSel +"\"]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

You can check that selector here

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

I made a little fiddle to test this. Here it is : 
https://jsfiddle.net/02mtamu1/

Apply this change to all your selectors.